# How to join 2 colums and remove some observations but keep others?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm not exactly sure how to express my question correctly...

Basically, I have 2 columns with about 2500 observations each. One is a directory of locations that exist (list1) and another is a list of locations regardless if they exist or not (list2). I want to do an *inner join* so that I'll keep all the locations that exist in list1 and remove the ones that don't from list2. But there is one location in particular that I want to keep which is 111, that is not in list1 where locations exist. So I thought I can do a *left join* with a *where clause* but I'm not sure what my where clause should look like.

For example,

```
+-------+--------+
| list1 |  list2 |
+-------+--------+
|    22 |     22 |
|    33 |     33 |
|    49 |     42 |
|    51 |     49 |
|    78 |     51 |
|   100 |     55 |
|       |     59 |
|       |     78 |
|       |    100 |
|       |    111 |
+-------+--------+
```

So I'd want my new list to look like this:

```
+-------+
|  list |
+-------+
|    22 |
|    33 |
|    49 |
|    51 |
|    78 |
|   100 |
|   111 |
+-------+
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using TSQL, you could also use a FULL JOIN for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM list1 l1
FULL JOIN list2 l2 ON l1.location = l2.location
WHERE l1.location IS NOT NULL
OR l2.location = 111
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all`:

```
select l1.location
from list1 l1
where exists (select 1 from list2 l2 where l2.location = l1.location)
union all
select 111;
```

Some databases might require a `from` clause for the second query, such as `from dual`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, this should work.
(This can generate the expected result you have shown above.)

```
Select list1 from yourTable
Union
Select list2 from yourTable
```

In addition, these links may help you.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: thank you but it won't... this will keep all unique observations. I need to keep the ones found on list1 but also keep 111 from list2

Comment: Do you only need 111 from list2? Nothing else... all(List1) + 111(list2)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't got your required:
Per your are description, it is list1 and 111?

```
     WITH testdata(list1,list2
      )AS (
        SELECT 22,22 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 33,33 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 49,42 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 51,49 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 78,51 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 100,55 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 0,59 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 0,78 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 0,100 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 0,111
    )

    SELECT list2 FROM testdata
    INTERSECT
    SELECT list1 FROM testdata 
    UNION
    SELECT 111
```

It will return:

```
list
22
33
49
51
78
100
111
```

Comment: this won't work since I have about 2500 observations.